# How to purposely create a malformed URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, xctest

I have the following Swift extension on `NSURL`

```
public extension NSURL {

    func getQueryItemValueForKey(key: String) -> String? {
        guard let components = NSURLComponents(URL: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return nil }
        return queryItems.filter {
            $0.name == key
            }.first?.value
    }

}
```

I am writing unit tests for it but I am unable to get 100% code coverage as I don't seem to be able to get `NSURLComponents(URL: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)` to return `nil`. From what I understand, this requires a malformed URL but I am struggling to create one.

I have tried:

- `let url = NSURL(string: "")`
- `let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example")`
- `let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.exam ple.com")`
- `let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/?param1=äëīòú")`

And some others that I lost track of. I know this is probably something blatantly obvious but i'm lost at the moment. So, how do I create a malformed URL in Swift?

Comment: The problem is that when you create NSURL like this - let url = NSURL(string: "") - the "url" is optional and if you try to unwrap it, you'll get nil inside. If you try calling url?.getQueryItemValueForKey - then this call is just not performed, because url is nil, i.e. you don't get NSURLComponents(...) to return nil because it's not called at all in case of malformed url.

Comment: @invisible_hand no, `NSURL(string: "")` is not `nil`, it is a valid `NSURL` instance. And if *"you don't get NSURLComponents(...) to return nil because [...]"* then why is it declared as an optional initializer?

Comment: Haha, you are right. But seems that I've found the answer. Try this: NSURL(string: "\\") or this NSURLComponents(string: "\\")

Comment: @invisible_hand unfortunately not - that simply gets you a `nil` `NSURL`, therefore you cannot pass it to `NSURLComponents` as `URL` parameter, in particular you do not even have a `self` in this context. The question is for "valid" `NSURL`, an instance of `NSURL` which fails to resolve into `NSURLComponents`.

Comment: @luk2302 okay, I agree again. After some research, it seems that NSURLComponents is based on more modern RFC standart and the only thing I could find is that this URL string is malformed for NSURLComponents - "http://example.com:-80/" (with "http://" in the beginning and negative port number), but is fine with NSURL, so can be used like topic starter wanted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As found in my research, you can produce a url that is malformed for NSURLComponents but not for NSURL by using negative port number (probably there are more cases but not sure):

```
let example = "http://example.com:-80/"
let url = NSURL(string: example)
print("url:\(url)") //prints out url:Optional(http://example.com:-80/)
if let url = url {
    let comps = NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    print("comps:\(comps)") //prints out comps:nil
}
```

Comment: Is the example there a valid url? I mean, should it be allowed to be created at all or is this a bug in Foundation? I don't understand the reasoning behind allowing a URL object to be created that cannot be rendered into components...